# In Android Emulator What is the number indicates

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

When loading multiple emulator at same time the emulator name should be 5554,5558,5556 followed by given name. What is that number indicates.

Comment: Emulator 1, console: 5554
Emulator 1, adb: 5555
Emulator 2, console: 5556
Emulator 2, adb: 5557 please refer http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These number indicates the port number at which emulator is running.

From android developer docs

> The console port number must be an even integer between 5554 and 5584,
>   inclusive.

[For more info](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Answer (score 2):

those are the port numbers on which ADB starts the service! Simultaneously you can run only 16 emulators in which first always runs at port number 5554.